# JS sessionStorage to store HTML node and then re-use it later

Tags: javascript, clone, session-storage

I need to clone some HTML content, store it in sessionStorage, to then re-deploy the stored HTML back into the DOM on another page. For the moment with my testing I'm just doing it all on one page and summoning the sessionStorage with a page refresh.

So, here is what I have come up with so far.

```
var exp561CardFour = document.getElementById('dashboard_item_four');
var clnCardFour = exp561CardFour.cloneNode(true);
sessionStorage.setItem('storedCardFour', clnCardFour);
```

When I go to grab the HTML with this bit of code in the console...

```
var grabCardFour = sessionStorage.getItem('storedCardFour');
```

...I end up with this:

[image]

Please help :)

edit:
FYI clnCardFour just contains some HTML and it works ok

[image]

edit with Parking Masters suggestion in the console:

[image]

Comment: what is inside `clnCardFour ` ? I think it is causing the error

Comment: Just edited the main post, but clnCardFour is fine and just holds some HTML. I've tested the general cloning function and it's ok, however the sessionStorage part here is where I'm struggling.

Comment: Please see my updated answer - it really is very simple. If you can explain how it doesn't match your requirements I'll be happy to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Storage API (sessionStorage/localStorage) only stores strings. When you call:

`sessionStorage.setItem('storedCardFour', clnCardFour);`

the API uses the `.toString()` method against the object `clnCardFour` - which returns `[object HTMLLIElement]`.

So you need the string representation of that Node. You can achieve that by getting the OuterHTML of the Node like this:

`sessionStorage.setItem('storedCardFour', clnCardFour.outerHTML);`

When you need to restore that Node, simply use the parent Node's `.innerHTML` property to place it back into the DOM.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let exp561CardFour = document.getElementById('dashboard_item_four');
sessionStorage.setItem('storedCardFour', exp561CardFour.outerHTML);
let clonedFromStorage = sessionStorage.getItem('storedCardFour');
div.innerHTML += clonedFromStorage
```

```html
<div>
  <i id="dashboard_item_four">Hello there!</i>
</div>
```

And here is a [JS Bin Example](https://jsbin.com/tudekoheku/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: The OP wanted the element object, not the string of what the element looks like.

Comment: @ParkingMaster You cannot store an object in sessionStorage - it must be serialized into a string. The OP can simply use `innerHTML` to restore it.

Comment: Yes you can, I explained it in my answer above where to store it, you use JSON.stringify which converts it to a string, and then parse it when getting it to turn it back to an object.

Comment: @ParkingMaster - "_which converts it to a string_" - exactly - which is not an object. You cannot store an Object in sessionStorage - it must be serialized. You offered on way, I offered a completely valid, but different way. It works, is effective and meets the Op's needs.

Comment: @ParkingMaster I'd like to see how to use suggested `JSON.stringify` for DOM nodes "easily". You see: `JSON.stringify((new DOMParser().parseFromString('<i class="x">?</i>','text/html')).body.childNodes[0])` produces just `"{}"` with no data you could recreate original element's clone from.
I can imagine you could roll out custom serializer, use DOM tree walker, slurp tag names and attributes into tree structure (effectively producing something akin shadow DOM) and stringify that, but compared to simple direct read/write of `.outerHTML` it seems like a massive overkill.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, I'm definitely grateful. I ended up using the solution from @RandyCasburn as it best matched the requirements. Wishing you a good week :)

Answer (score -1):

The `HTMLIElement` is an `<i>` element, you're storing the entire element object in the storage.

You can use `JSON` (JavaScript **Object** Notation) `.stringify({})` to stringify the element and then parse it again to get the element.

Here's an example of that:

```js
var myEl = document.getElementById("my-el");

alert("This will not print the object: " + myEl);

alert("This will print the object: " + JSON.stringify(myEl));
```

```html
<i id="my-el"></i>
```

Overflowed objects are not stringified as the object is too long.

With jQuery:

```js
var myEl = $("my-el");

alert("This will not print the jQuery object: " + myEl);

alert("This will print the jQuery object: " + JSON.stringify(myEl));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i id="my-el"></i>
```

*More about [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) at MDN.*

---

(Be careful what you store in `sessionStorage`, you can only store up to 2kB at a time).

Now to get the parsed object using `JSON.parse`:

```js
var myObj = "{}";

myObj; // "{}"

JSON.parse(myObj); // Object { ... }
```

I've put together a live example of everything:

```js
var exp561CardFour = document.getElementById('dashboard_item_four');
var clnCardFour = exp561CardFour.cloneNode(true);
sessionStorage.setItem('storedCardFour', JSON.stringify(clnCardFour));

// When in an <iframe>, it'll say The operation is insecure."

var grabCardFour = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('storedCardFour'));
```

```html
<i id="dashboard_item_four"><i>
```

The code snippet is from <kbd>stacksnippets.net</kbd> and will not work because of iframe security issues.

However, try it on your local server / file, and good luck.

Comment: Thank you Parking Master. However when I try your live code into the console and then summon the variable grabCardFour, it returns what looks like an empty JSON object. I'm hoping to see the entire HTML block which was copied. I've updated the first post with a screenshot.

Comment: As I said, JSON.stringify doesn't display long objects. But the object still works.